# how to decrypt password in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

When i opened the database the password looks like this

```
|user_name|user_pass                         |
|--------------------------------------------|
|marse    |$1$ma000000$4zr8TJkJ9zS60NuToTxjA.|
```

I know that my password is not like that because I created that account for testing purposes but when I opened the database the password become like that. Is there some encryption going on? If there is, how to decrypt it?
Because currently I am working on a login page, where my php code will compare the user input with the one with the database.
The code that I use to compare is like this

```
<?php

// Grab User submitted information
$name = $_POST["users_name"];
$pass = $_POST["users_pass"];

// Connect to the database
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password");
// Make sure we connected succesfully
if(! $con)
{
    die('Connection Failed'.mysql_error());
}

// Select the database to use
mysqli_select_db("cvgcrm",$con);

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = $name");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($row["user_name"]==$name && $row["user_pass"]==$pass)
    echo"You are a validated user.";
else
    echo"Sorry, your credentials are not valid, Please try again.";
?>
```

Comment: You can't. The password isn't even encrypted, it's hashed. Hashing is a one-way function, so it can't be reversed.

Comment: so how do i compare a hashed password with the one that the user inputs?

Comment: Hash the password with the same hashing function. If it matches what you have in the database, then the password must be correct.

Comment: generate the hashing password from here (http://i-tools.org/hash) and then check if matches with your hashing password otherwise put the hashing password into database and use that password

Comment: By the way, your code is very insecure. ① Never *ever* put user-supplied data straight into a MySQL query without escaping it first (e.g., `$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['users_name']);`) ② You need to check the return values from `mysqli_query()` and `mysqli_fetch_array()`. Otherwise I could pass validation by running your script with `$name` and `$pass` both as empty strings.

Comment: we need to see the code that was used to create the account

Comment: voted to close as unclear, until we know how the password was created and generated and which algo used for it. Looks to be MD5 though

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Answer (score 1):

The encrypted password comes automatically when you are installing any CMS or eCommerce framework. You need to clarify that which framework you are using. If you are using wordpress then password cannot be decrypted but you can change. In phpmyadmin:

Select the table, click on structure. On password field choose type as 'MD5' enter your new password and save it.

You can get your new password with encrypted format.
Enjoy.